# Can tcp client and server written in C++ and built with different compiler cause write/read to fail

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I am writing a single threaded blocking tcp client on Linux that just sends requests to existing well tested server and waits for the response from it. Server and client are compiled with different compilers. My client code looks like below :-

```
char buf[sizeof(MyMsg) + sizeof(MySignon) + 10]={0};
MyMsg *msg = reinterpret_cast<MyMsg*>(buf);
MySignon *signOn = reinterpret_cast<MySignon*>(msg->mstrt); //mstrt is double type

msg->type= SIGNON;
msg->subtype= USER_SIGNON;
strncpy(signOn->szUserId, user, sizeof(signOn->szUserId)-1);
signOn->iApplicationMode =  SM_SIGN_ALLOC;
SetMsgLen(msg, sizeof(MySignon));

auto ret = send(fd, reinterpret_cast<char*>(msg), msg->msglen);
```

and send looks like below :-

```
Status Send(int fd, char* data, size_t length)
{
    size_t written = 0;
    errno=0;
    do{
         MyMsg* pm = reinterpret_cast<MyMsg*>(data+written);
         int r = ::write(fd, pm, length-written);

         if (errno == 0)
             written+=r;

     } while (length > written and errno == 0);
}
```

The Problem :- When I run this, server receives a very large size from `msg->msglen`. There is another client which does exactly same steps and which is compiled with same compiler as server that works fine. That is why I suspect different compilers might be treating structures in different way (may be due to struct padding).
What is wrong here. What is work around for this problem.

Comment: Compilers are allowed to pad structures as they see fit; there is no standardized in-memory layout for C++ objects.  That's why it's important to do proper serialization when sending and receiving data across the network, if you want any kind of portability.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815764/how-does-one-properly-deserialize-a-byte-array-back-into-an-object-in-c/44816991#44816991

Comment: Strange struct packing is why you should use `static_assert` with sizeof and offsetof to guarantee that structs are the correct size and members are in correct locations. Either that or make or find some kind of Decoder object which takes a reference or pointer to a buffer and maintains a pointer while providing functions like `get_uint32le`

Comment: The very first thing you should do is dump your received message buffer as hexadecimal in a debugger or make your own print statement. I suspect you either did not get the data you expected, or it is in a different format such as big-endian.

Comment: And of course, your code as written here would never work at all. Why not post the actual program or at least a link to it.